# Resolving Python dependencies at installation time in setup.py based on an interpreter version

Tags: python, pip, dependency-management

Suppose I have a bunch of requirement files like:

```
requirements.txt   # common for both 2.x and 3.x
requirements-2.txt # 2.x
requirements-3.txt # 3.x
```

and I would like to populate `install_requires` argument in `setup.py` file based on the current Python interpreter version. Assume of course that **pip** handles the installation process.

**Solution 1:** Of course, I can write a simple function that will read and return correct requirements. In a case with multiple projects this is obviously not acceptable, since I will have to copy the function everywhere.

**Solution 2:** Next idea here is to write a simple package that does it for me, but the problem is that it should be available not only at distribution time (like `python setup.py sdist`), but more importantly, at installation time on one's machine.

I was managed to write a simple module that does the thing, lets call it `depmodule`. I also  had following `setup.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

try:
    from depmodule import find_requirements
except ImportError:
    # this line is executed when reading setup.py for the first time
    # since depmodule is not installed yet
    find_requirements = lambda: []

setup(
    name='some-package',
    packages=find_packages(),
    # snip...
    platforms='any',

    # note that depmodule is listed here as a requirement, so it will be
    # installed before some-package, thus will be available when it comes
    # to running setup.py of some-package
    install_requires=['depmodule'] + find_requirements(),
)
```

When it comes to `pip install some-package` it **actually resolves dependencies correctly**, but they are not picked up by pip, so it only installs: `depmodule some-package` (in that order) instead of `depmodule dep1 dep2 ... some-package`.

I tried to use `setup_requires` argument but with no luck. The dependency was downloaded, but I could not access it, since it was an egg package (not extracted).

Is there any way I can overcome this issue? Are there any alternatives (other approaches) that could help with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not want to replicate code for multiple projects you might consider generating the `setup.py` and/or updating some part of setup.py from from a single source.
This would be similar to generate a `Makefile` from a `Makefile.in` template.

I have a `py_setup` program for this. I call it with `py_setup --new` to generate a new `setup.py` in the current directory, taking parts of py_setup as a template. When `py_setup` is 
run with a filename as argument, it tries to update segments in that file but leaves the rest of them untouched.
When run without arguments and without options `py_setup` does update segments on all `*/setup.py` files.

The segments in `py_setup` (and the setup.py files) are seperated by comment lines of the form `#_## segement_name` or ended with `#_#`. Anything before or between segments is copied, but will never get updated in the `setup.py`
Anything after the line `#_###` in the py_setup is never copied, that is the actual code that is the actual `py_setup` program code

Most lines are copied verbatim, except for the segment separator comments (stripped after the segment name) and the line that starts with:

```
setup = setup
```

From that line `setup =` is stripped at the start, so it ends up as a call to setup() in the setup.py but not when running `py_setup`.

When updating, only **existing** segments that are in the target `setup.py` are replaced with lines from the same named segments in `py_setup`. Removing or changing the segment name makes sure code changes will not be udpated.